# ODI-30104: Model Internal ID is not supported when Legacy ID Compatible Mode is switched off

Tags: groovy, oracle-data-integrator

We are using ODI 12c

We have created a scenario to execute the package in which we add the commands for reverse engineer the model.

Below is the script we used but this is giving us an error for the model Id:

> ODI-30104: Model Internal ID is not supported when Legacy ID Compatible Mode is switched off

Is there any way we can extract the global Id of the model using groovy script?

```
OdiPackage pkg = new OdiPackage(folder, "Pkg_Rev" + "SQL_MODEL5");
StepOdiCommand step1 = new StepOdiCommand(pkg,"step1_cmd_reset");
step1.setCommandExpression(new Expression("OdiReverseResetTable \"-MODEL="+mod.getModelId()+"\"",null, Expression.SqlGroupType.NONE));
StepOdiCommand step2 = new StepOdiCommand(pkg,"step2_cmd_reset");
step2.setCommandExpression(new Expression("OdiReverseGetMetaData \"-MODEL="+mod.getModelId()+"\"",null, Expression.SqlGroupType.NONE));
StepOdiCommand step3 = new StepOdiCommand(pkg,"step3_cmd_reset");
step3.setCommandExpression(new Expression("OdiReverseSetMetaData \"-MODEL="+mod.getModelId()+"\"",null, Expression.SqlGroupType.NONE));

pkg.setFirstStep(step1);
step1.setNextStepAfterSuccess(step2);
step2.setNextStepAfterSuccess(step3);
tme.persist(pkg)
tm.commit(txnStatus)
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, only Global ID (GUIDs) are used in 12c. So there is a change in both the SDK and the substitution API.

Most of the objects — including [OdiModel](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/odi/reference-java-api/oracle/odi/domain/model/OdiModel.html) — in ODI now inherits the getGlobalId() method from class oracle.odi.domain.support.AbstractRepositoryEntity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response, your resolution worked for me.

Comment: Glad it helped and welcome to Stack Overflow @SantoshKadam . If this answer or any future answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. It ensures future readers find directly what worked and it give a little reward to whoever helped you.